# How to read BPMN2.0 xml data to jbpm5.5 internally?

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

I mean read BPMN2.O XML data into jBPM5.5 API with the help of any **jBPM Xmlparser**

Here i am exactly looking for XML parser for extract the data from **BPMN2.0 xml** to **jBPM5.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void readBPMNFileMetaInfo() throws Exception {
              KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration conf = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration();
              ((PackageBuilderConfiguration) conf).initSemanticModules();
              ((PackageBuilderConfiguration) conf).addSemanticModule(new BPMNSemanticModule());
              ((PackageBuilderConfiguration) conf).addSemanticModule(new BPMNDISemanticModule());
              XmlProcessReader processReader = new XmlProcessReader(
                           ((PackageBuilderConfiguration) conf).getSemanticModules(), getClass().getClassLoader());
              List<Process> process = processReader.read(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("OrderCheck.bpmn").getInputStream());
              //String asXml = XmlBPMNProcessDumper.INSTANCE.dump((WorkflowProcess) process, XmlBPMNProcessDumper.NO_META_DATA);
              for(Process p : process){
                     RuleFlowProcess rp=(RuleFlowProcess)p;
                     Node[] nodes=rp.getNodes();

                      for(Node n : nodes) {
                           System.out.println(n.getId());
                           System.out.println(n.getName());
                           System.out.println(n.getIncomingConnections());
                           System.out.println(n.getOutgoingConnections());
                     }
                     System.out.println("Done");
              }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the file by:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("MyProcess.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2);
KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("com.sample.MyProcess");
```